# How to iterate over htmlCollection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm having some difficulty with this.  In Backbone, I have a function like this:

```
 functionOne: function(){
        $('#myTExtbox-' + budgetLine.attr('id')).on('change keyup paste', function(){
           that.mySecondFunction(this);
        });
 }
```

In this case, the `this` is a `textbox`, which is in a `table`, inside a `div`.  Then:

```
mySecondFunction: function(tb){
       var tbody = tb.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
       //gets main parent, which is a tbody, inside a table, inside a div

}
```

I then want to iterate over `tbody`, to go through each row and find a `textbox` in a specific cell.  The problem is that this code:

```
    $.each(tbody, function(index, item){
        cost = item;
        var t= index;
    });
```

Doesn't seem to allow me to get to any of the items. In this example, if I try to do something like:

```
  item.getElementById('test');
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLCollection> has no method 'getElementById'
```

Why can't I iterate over this object and access objects within?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/HX8RL/14/

Essentially, what should happen is this:  When a text box changes, I want to iterate over all the rows in the tb's parent table and sum all the Tb values.  Keeping in mind, all the tb's in the same cell position, as there could be other tb's in other places that I dont want to include.

Comment: Try item[index].getElementById('test') and see if this works;

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I've tried that to no avail

Comment: I added a fiddle now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wont be any collection of `TBody`
try using `children()` instead

```
$.each(tbody.children('tr'), function(index, item){
        cost = item;
        var t= index;
    });
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/HX8RL/)

Comment: I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'children' of object #<HTMLInputElement> is not a function"

Comment: Actually, this led me to the final solution.  Instead of tbody.children('tr'), it's tbody.rows.  Thanks

Comment: [Dec 2015] I found this answer during a search and it didn't work for my purposes. For anyone else who may stumble across this, what worked for iterating over an htmlcollection was a basic javascript for loop. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over all input elements directly to get values.

```
var tbody = tb.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    alert(tbody.id);
    var input = $('#tbody').find('input');
    alert(input);
    console.log(input);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        alert(input[i].value);
        alert(i);
    }
```

See fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/HX8RL/18/

Comment: it was the true answer I was looking for, saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things going wrong here. You know you can only have one ID per page? So you have to do `document.getElementByid('test')` instead.

Since you are also using jQuery you can use the find function, `item.find('#test')`. But I think this wouldn't solve you problem. Not sure what you want to achieve, maybe I can help you if you explain a bit more in detail what your problem is.

Also

```
tb.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
```

can be written as (in jQuery)

```
$(tb).parents('tbody');
```

I've setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6VvRd/), maybe it can help you.

**Code used in fiddle:**

```
var myFuncs = (function() {

    function funcA() {
        $('input').on('keyup', function() {
           funcB(this); 
        });
    }

    function funcB(myInput) {
        var $table = $(myInput).parents('table');

        $table.find('tr > td > input').each(function() {
           var $input = $(this);

            if($(myInput).attr('id') != $input.attr('id'))
                $input.val("I'm called from another input");
        });
    }

    return {
        funcA : funcA
    }

})();

myFuncs.funcA();
```